# Using Count Condition

Tags: sql

i have a table consist of Truck Id & Mileage where Truck ID can be duplicated (trips). 
I want a query that shows the Max(mileage)-Min(Mileage) but only if the count of Truck Id > 1.
Excuse me i am still a beginner in this world.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Did our answers help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select Max(mileage)-Min(Mileage) as diff, TruckID
from tableTruck
group by truckid
having count(truckid) > 1
```

Use this query

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `GROUP BY ... HAVING`:

```
SELECT MAX(mileage)-MIN(Mileage), Truck_Id
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Truck_Id
HAVING COUNT(Truck_id) > 1
```

A little tutorial with examples on the `HAVING` clause you find here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp